# change the dataframe model on the external condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-3.6

If the dataframe is:

```
id  name    nicknames
1   i-123   sg-123
1   i-123   sg-234
1   i-123   sg-345
2   i-456   sg-654
2   i-456   sg-765
2   i-789   sg-875
2   i-789   sg-123
2   i-789   sg-987
2   i-789   sg-765
```

The list is:

```
prob = ['sg-123','sg-234','sg-345','sg-456','sg-567','sg-678']
```

Check if the df['nicknames'] is in prob list and generate the below dataframe from the above df.

First 3 column rows should be reduced as we need list of nicknames for each name as in expected resultant dataframe. 
**4th column**: if the nicknames isin prob, then print the nicknames in this column as list. 
**5th column**: if the nicknames is not in prob, then print the nicknames in this column as list.
**6th column**: count of the 4th column
**7th column**: count of the 5th column. 
Expected resultant Dataframe:

```
id  name    nicknames                               exist                           not_exist                       count_exist count_not_exist
1   i-123   ['sg-123',' sg-234',' sg-345']          ['sg-123',' sg-234',' sg-345']  Null                            3           0
2   i-456   ['sg-654','sg-765']                     Null                            ['sg-654','sg-765']             0           2
2   i-789   ['sg-875','sg-123','sg-987','sg-765']   ['sg-123']                      ['sg-875','sg-987','sg-765']    1           3
```

Comment: Can you add  some more details..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d = df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).nicknames.agg(list)

e = d.nicknames.map(lambda x: [*{*x} & {*prob}])
n = d.nicknames.map(lambda x: [*{*x} - {*prob}])
d.assign(exist=e, not_exist=n, count_exist=e.str.len(), count_not_exist=n.str.len())
```

---

```
   id   name                         nicknames                     exist                 not_exist  count_exist  count_not_exist
0   1  i-123          [sg-123, sg-234, sg-345]  [sg-234, sg-123, sg-345]                        []            3                0
1   2  i-456                  [sg-654, sg-765]                        []          [sg-654, sg-765]            0                2
2   2  i-789  [sg-875, sg-123, sg-987, sg-765]                  [sg-123]  [sg-987, sg-875, sg-765]            1                3
```

Comment: The function `lambda x: [*{*x} & {*prob}]` takes an argument `x` and makes a `set` out of it with `{*x}` it then intersects with the `set` `{*prob}` by doing `{*x} & {*prob}`and makes a list out of that `[*{*x} & {*prob}]`.  It is the same as `lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(prob))`.  On the other hand `map` applies that function to all members of the `Series`.  The other function `lambda x: [*{*x} - {*prob}]` does set differencing instead of intersection.

Comment: getting error : "Shape of passed values is (6, 705), indices imply (1, 705)"

I removed 'name' column in the groupby line.
Used: d = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).nicknames.agg(list)

Cant i remove/skip the column "name" in d DataFrame?

@piRSquared

Comment: You get that error when you are attempting to construct a new dataframe with an array of data that has a shape of 6 rows and 705 columns but you only passed an index of length 1 and columns of length 705.  You are obviously using other data than the sample data provided in the question.  If the code above works for the sample data but **Not** your actual data, you'll have to better describe the real situation.  Otherwise, I have no way to really know what is happening.

Comment: I see you edited your comment.  Trying to catch up (-:

Comment: It worked for the question, but i tried to use the same thing for the dataframe which has more columns and i need 1st column and a 5th column as list with respect to 1st column.

Comment: When I removed `name` I ran into a different problem.  This fixed the problem I found `df.groupby(['id']).nicknames.agg(list).reset_index()`